# System.Format Exception. in LINQToEXCEL

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-excel

in my MVC 5 application, i am using LinqToExcel to import data from Excel file to SQL Server Database table. Following is the code for getting the data and saving to the database.

```
var dataDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Data/"));
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dataDirectory.ToString());//reading the director at a specific path
            FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles("*.*");//getting the list of files in the director
            foreach(FileInfo f in info)
            {
                dataFileName = f.FullName;//getting full file name
                fileExt = f.Extension;//getting the file extension
            }
            if(fileExt == ".xlsx")
            {
                var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
                excel.FileName = dataFileName;
                //mapping the database table columns to EXCEL columns
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.AccountNo, "ACCOUNTNO");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.BillNo, "BILLNO");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Category, "CATEGORY");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Billing_Period, "BILLING_PERIOD");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Name, "NAME");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Address, "ADDRESS");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Issue_Date, "ISSUE_DATE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Due_Date, "DUE_DATE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Water_Bill, "WATER_BILL");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Sewerage_Bill, "SEWERAGE_BILL");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Aquifer_Charges, "AQUIFER");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Current_Amount, "CURRENT AMOUNT");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Arrears, "ARREARS");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Service_Charges, "SERVICE CHARGES");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Payable_within_DueDate, "PAYABLE WITHIN DUEDATE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Surcharge, "SURCHARGE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Payable_after_DueDate, "AFTER DUE DATE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Payment_History_1, "PAY HISTORY 1");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Paid_1, "PAID 1");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Payment_History_2, "PAY HISTORY 2");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Paid_2, "PAID 2");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Payment_History_3, "PAY HISTORY 3");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Paid_3, "PAID 3");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Area, "AREA");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Water_Rate, "WATER RATE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Sewerage_Rate, "SEWER RATE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Discharge_Basis, "DISCHAGE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Pump_Size, "PUMP SIZE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Ferrule_Size, "FERRULE SIZE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Meter_Type, "METER TYPE");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Meter_Status, "METER STATUS");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Current_Reading, "CURRENT READING");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Last_Readin, "LAST READING");
                excel.AddMapping<WASA_Bill_Detail>(s => s.Water_Aquiffer_Charges, "WATER AQUIFER CHARGES");

                var excelData = from x in excel.Worksheet<WASA_Bill_Detail>() select x;                

                foreach(var data in excelData)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        db.WASA_Bill_Detail.Add(wASA_Bill_Detail);
                        db.SaveChanges();                        
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

in the above code i did the property mapping to the excel columns.

Now the problem is when i tried to save the data into the database table, the "System.FormatException" occurred. the exception details are as under

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
       at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
       at LinqToExcel.Extensions.CommonExtensions.Cast(Object object, Type castType)
       at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryExecutor.GetTypeResults(IDataReader data, IEnumerable`1 columns, QueryModel queryModel)
       at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryExecutor.GetDataResults(SqlParts sql, QueryModel queryModel)
       at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryExecutor.ExecuteCollection[T](QueryModel queryModel)
       at Remotion.Data.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSequenceInfo.ExecuteCollectionQueryModel[T](QueryModel queryModel, IQueryExecutor executor)
       at Remotion.Data.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSequenceInfo.ExecuteQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel, IQueryExecutor executor)
       at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryModel.Execute(IQueryExecutor executor)
       at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryProviderBase.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
       at LINQToSQLTest.Controllers.WASA_Bill_DetailController.Create(WASA_Bill_Detail wASA_Bill_Detail, HttpPostedFileBase[] Files) in e:\Projects\DotNet\MVC5\LINQToSQLTest\LINQToSQLTest\Controllers\WASA_Bill_DetailController.cs:line 133
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41()
  InnerException:
```

any help regarding the above exception

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: on 'db.SaveChanges(); ' this line

Comment: I would guess that you want to save a decimal point number and use the wrong formatting depending on the regional settings.

Comment: In excel, there is some cell value is not decimal number that you want

Comment: I just noticed that i have some decimal fields in my database table and in excel there is string values. Now the question is that how i can get the value of that specific column and convert to decimal.

Comment: LInqtoexcel has its own parsing mechanism, its better to have all data in string and then manipulate later by code.